# alert dialog not working properly in Broadcast Reciever class

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

First of all i am creating an **Android** Application whose primary requirement is Network Connection.My app needs network connection all the time. So i have made a *broadcast* *Receiver* class for checking availability of the connection.
If the connection is not available then I am showing a dialog  which forces the user to connect to the network, else exit from the application and **dialog** is not **cancelable** .
So the problem is that,I am getting that if i run my application (With network connected) it just works fine as expected the dialog comes if disconnect the network and goes away if I connect the network again, but when I start my app (without network connected) then that dialog comes and never goes away even if i connect the network.Below is my **ConnectionStatusReceiver** class *Also please tell me is this a right approach ? And How can i change the whole Content view Like Amazon application shows a dog's image when connection is not available ??* 
basically i wanted my app to restrict user to do anything if notwork is not available.

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectionStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private AlertDialog.Builder alertadd;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private boolean isDialogOpen = false;
    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    ConnectionStatusReceiver(){
    }


    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {

        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                final NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (ni != null) {
                    return (ni.isConnected() && (ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE));
                }
            } else {
                final Network n = cm.getActiveNetwork();

                if (n != null) {
                    final NetworkCapabilities nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(n);

                    return (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI));
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(isOnline(context)){

                if (isDialogOpen) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                isDialogOpen = false;
                MyToast.showToast(context, "Connection Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            }else{

                alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.no_connection_error_dialog, null);
                alertadd.setView(view);

                alertadd.setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                alertadd.setCancelable(false);
                dialog = alertadd.create();
                dialog.show();
                isDialogOpen = true;
                MyToast.showToast(context, "Connection Lost!\nPlease connect to a Network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use AlertDialog without activity context. But if you really want show dialog without activity context then use below code :

```
public void showDialog(Context context) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Title");
    dialog.getWindow().setType(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
    dialog.show();
}
```

And add following permission to `AndroidManifiest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: the Activity context i am already getting through OnRecieve(Context context, Intent intent); and dialog is displaying but m unable to close that dialog when network is connected.

Comment: ok then define your dialog as static and when  network is connected dismiss your dialog.

Comment: please see my code above and correct it where i am wrong

Comment: try to change private AlertDialog dialog; to private static AlertDialog dialog;

Comment: nope making it static made even worse situation the dialog box is never dismissed now

Comment: ok i got the problem in this approach that after the ConnectionStatusReciever class done its work the objects get destroyed with dialog box opened so there is no more reference to that Dialog object

Comment: but what alternative should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

okay i got the solution by ***myself***
i've just chnaged the if conditions like this

```
if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

if(dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing()) 
                    //showDialog
```